# Wordpress thumbnail from category as background div

Tags: php, wordpress, background, thumbnails

I've got a problem with Wordpress.

I want the thumbnail of my last post as background of my div.

**Code:**

```
<div<?php

    if ( $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id() ) {
        if ( $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'normal-bg' ) )
            printf( ' style="background-image: url(%s);"id="photopost"', $image_src[0] );     
    }

?><?php $cat_id = 3; //the certain category ID
$latest_cat_post = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => 1, 'category__in' => array($cat_id)));
if( $latest_cat_post->have_posts() ) : while( $latest_cat_post->have_posts() ) : $latest_cat_post->the_post();  ?><?php endwhile; endif; ?>></div>
```

This works fine with the thumbnail of my last post (all post).
But i want the thumbnail from the last post of category ID 3.

How can i fix this?

Thanks,
Bjorn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the Query after you have created the thumbnail. The Query should wrap the div.

Try:

```
<?php $cat_id = 3; //the certain category ID
$latest_cat_post = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => 1, 'category__in' => array($cat_id)));
if( $latest_cat_post->have_posts() ) : while( $latest_cat_post->have_posts() ) : $latest_cat_post->the_post();  ?>

<div<?php

    if ( $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id() ) {
        if ( $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'normal-bg' ) )
            printf( ' style="background-image: url(%s);"id="photopost"', $image_src[0] );     
    }

?>></div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```